# Please check my answer to a pseudocode CASE statement question

Tags: pseudocode

This is a pseudocode question in my IGCSE CompSci textbook:

> Use a `CASE` statement to display the day of the week if the variable `DAY` has the value 1 to 7 and an error otherwise.

This is my answer to it:

```
CASE Day OF
    1 : OUTPUT "Monday"
    2 : OUTPUT "Tuesday"
    3 : OUTPUT "Wednesday"
    4 : OUTPUT "Thursday"
    5 : OUTPUT "Friday"
    6 : OUTPUT "Saturday"
    7 : OUTPUT "Sunday"
    OTHERWISE OUTPUT "Day invalid"
ENDCASE
```

Is this answer correct?

(I realise this is a very rudimentary question for a Year 10/11 CompSci class but I’m homeschooled with no teaching guidance whatsoever. So a big cheers to anyone who would take the time to check my answer for me.)

Comment: May be a more appropriate question for stackoverflow?

Comment: An interesting problem is that different countries don't agree which is the first day of the week. If this is in the USA, you might get 0 points because you didn't put Sunday first. And as a software developer, you wouldn't call the variable "Day" but "Weekday".

Comment: What could be wrong in this answer ??

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about switch-case statements. So, if you can do a pseudo-code of such a statement with the case being a DAY variable and the steps are clear, that would be correct.
So, your answer is totally correct and the steps are clear. There's no one way of doing pseudo code.

```
switch(DAY)
    case 1:
        print("Monday")
    case 2:
        print("Tuesday")
    case 3:
        print("Wednesday")
    case 4:
        print("Thursday")
    case 5:
        print("Friday")
    case 6:
        print("Saturday")
    case 7:
        print("Sunday")
    default:
        print("Invalid Day!")
```

Above is another possible way to a case statement for the **DAY** variable as your question expects.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in pseudo-code terms, it looks OK.
Speaking in syntax terms, as the answer from @Geeth Sandaru looks to be correct. 
In C/C++ however, you would need `break` statements after each `print` (apart from the last one).

@Apoorv is right though, this might be more suited to stack overflow.

Comment: In Swift, the compiler might warn you about your unnecessary break statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct but should be specifying 'break' in every case expect the last one because in the switch case the following statement also gets executed.